# List of dictionaries: remove duplicates while keeping part of the dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, blockchain

I have a list of dictionaries and I would like to ***remove duplicates while keeping some informations***.

For contexts, these are blockchain transactions. The informations are:

- transaction hash,
- ID of the NFT,
- value of the transaction (it can be buying, selling or minting price).

In the original list below every action is separated. However, I realized that some have the same hash so they are just one transaction with multiple actions (in this case minting 2 NFTs in one transaction). So y goal is to have a cleaned list with only the individual transactions (identified by their hash) and the multiple IDs separated by a comma if there are multiple actions in one transaction, and the total price.

```
original_list = [
  {
    'hash': '12345',
    'ID': '355',
    'price': 12
  },
  {
    'hash': '12345',
    'ID': '356',
    'price': 12
  },
  {
    'hash': '635',
    'ID': '355',
    'price': 30
  },
  {
    'hash': '637',
    'ID': '356',
    'price': 35
  }
]
```

Here is the end result I want:

```
clean_list = [
  {
    'hash': '12345',
    'ID': '355, 356',
    'price': 12
  },
  {
    'hash': '635',
    'ID': '355',
    'price': 30
  },
  {
    'hash': '637',
    'ID': '356',
    'price': 35
  }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). We do not want questions to include stuff about you - the question should only be about the code, and the problem you are trying to solve. It also usually goes much better for you if you demonstrate that you have [tried to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: Instead of joining up the ID strings like `'355, 356'`, how about making a list like `['355', '356']`? I think you would find it easier to work with that data later, for example to iterate over the IDs.

Comment: Here's a strategy: try to make a dictionary where the keys are the `'hash'` values and the values are the original dictionaries from your list; but if you find that a `'hash'` value is already in the dictionary, update the `'ID'` instead of adding an entry. Then you can take the values from that dictionary as your final list. This sort of thing is good practice for Python fundamentals, and you should make sure you can handle that kind of thing before trying to solve your own problems - especially if you're going to get into some specialized field like blockchain stuff.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks for your help, I am going to study that more and my next questions are going to be better thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through your list and create a new dictionary where you merge the data:

```
def exist_in_list[hash,lst]: #function that checks if the hash is already in the list and returns the index if it does
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]['hash']==hash:
            return i
    return -1
new_list = []
for dict in clean_list:
    index = exist_in_list(dict['hash'],new_list):
    if index<0:
        new_list.append(dict)
    else:
        new_list[index]['ID'] += f", {dict['ID']}"
```

There may be some small syntax errors but the logic is there.
 You loop through the first list, check if the dictionary is in the new one, if it isn't then you add it and if it is, you add the new ID in it.

Comment: Happy it did  !‎‎